# Amphora does not get an IP

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to deploy Octavia on Openstack Ussuri using openstack-ansible on Ubuntu 20.04.

I followed the documentation and set a flat provider network for the communication between amphora and the control plan.

I can see the amphora instances been create, but I keep having this error on octavia:

```
Oct 03 17:20:34 controller-r316n01-octavia-server-container-21012611 octavia-housekeeping[73]: 2020-10-03 17:20:34.715 73 WARNING octavia.amphorae.drivers.haproxy.rest_api_driver [-] Could not connect to instance. Retrying.: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.29.232.146', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: // (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9012e80940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))
Oct 03 17:20:42 controller-r316n01-octavia-server-container-21012611 octavia-housekeeping[73]: 2020-10-03 17:20:42.780 73 WARNING octavia.amphorae.drivers.haproxy.rest_api_driver [-] Could not connect to instance. Retrying.: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.29.232.146', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: // (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9012e80310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))
```

So I took a look on the instance and saw that it did not get an IP.

```
[  303.862574] cloud-init[426]: Cloud-init v. 20.3-2-g371b392c-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running   'init' at Sat, 03 Oct 2020 17:09:35 +0000. Up 303.78 seconds.
[  303.863638] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[  303.864525] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[  303.865366] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address            |    Mask   | Scope |     Hw-Address    |
[  303.867859] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[  303.869086] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: |  ens3  | True | fe80::f816:3eff:fedb:b398/64 |     .     |  link | fa:16:3e:db:b3:98 |
[  303.870261] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1           | 255.0.0.0 |  host |         .         |
[  303.871316] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128            |     .     |  host |         .         |
[  303.873887] cloud-init[426]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

I do not know where to look at, but it seems that the DHCP is not working on my flat provider network. Do someone have some idea where I can look at, or why my setup is not working?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know very little about OSA, but generally I'd check for the *enable_dhcp* flag in the provider network's subnet. If TRUE, I'd find the dnsmasq process responsible for this network and check its logs or leases. In the worst case, run *tcpdump* to find out what happens with the amphora's DHCP requests.

Comment: If FALSE, there must be a YAML key to set it.

Comment: Using the tcpdump I saw I had an issue with my LXC networks, and I cleared the IPs and rerun the playbooks. I do not know if it worked as Nova cannot talk to rabbitmq anymore.

Comment: *Nova cannot talk to rabbitmq anymore* I'd say you did not really improve things, unfortunately.

Comment: So update, I managed to fix nova. And I found where the issue is. So I have my neutron-dhcp agent on a namespace. And I have a bridge (br-lbaas) to the flat network where my Amphora instances are. But, my neutron-agent, instead of being connected to the br-lbaas bridge, it is connected to a bridge connected to nothing. 
If I change manually the master for the neutron-dhcp-agent, everything works. But if I reboot my controller, everything breaks again. I need now to find how tell neutron to connect the agent to the br-lbaas bridge instead of the one he creates.

Comment: I got the config I need on the controllers. I need to add:

[linux_bridge]

bridge_mappings = lbaas:br-lbaas

Comment: Congratulations!